# Not sure why this Regex is returning true

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use this regex to verify usernames and this is what I have :

```
var goodUsername  = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]/g;

console.log(goodUsername.test("HELO $"));
```

But wether or not I have `$` in there it returns true. Not sure why.

I basically only want letters, numbers and _ in usernames and that's it

It seems to work here https://regex101.com/r/nP4iG7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx that you use searches any match in the subject string. In your case *HELO* matches the criteria. If you like to apply the criteria to the whole string you should define the string begin and end using

```
var goodUsername  = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;
console.log(goodUsername.test("HELO $"));//false
```

Comment: Actually, HELO does not match, but H does.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually every letter in *HELO* matches the RegExp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add anchors..

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;
```

Anchors help to do exact matching. `^` start of the line anchor, `$` end of the line anchor. And also you need to repeat the char class one or more times otherwise it would match a string which contains exactly one character.

Comment: Minor nit: this is a character set, not a character class.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was going by the MDN page which uses "character set" for `[]` and "character class" for `\w`. I suppose your link is more authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for any characters **not** in the list (a "negated [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets)"):

```
var badUsername = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/;

console.log(!badUsername.test("HELO $"));
```

or more simply

```
var badUsername = /\W/;
```

since `\W` is defined as

> Matches any character that is not a word character from the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.

If you prefer to do a positive match, using anchors as other answers have suggested, you can shorten your regexp by using `\w`:

```
var goodUsername = /^\w+$/;
```